# onActivityResult NOT WORKING -- FOR SOME REASON THE CODE DOESNT REACH THE onActivityResult FUNCTION

Tags: android-studio

````
``` @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            selected=themeAdapter.getItem(i);
    
            Intent intent=new Intent(Themes.this,Game.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",selected.getTheme_name());
            intent.putExtra("bitmap",Helper.bitmapToByteArray(selected.getTheme_pic()));
            intent.putExtra("position",i);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    
        }
    --HERE IS THE CALL FOR THE FUNCTION  
      
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if(requestCode==0){
                    Log.d("workk"," "+data.getStringExtra("position"));
                }
        ```

-- HERE IS THE FUNCTION
````

for some reason when the user back from the ONITEMCLICK function the onactivity result not starting

Comment: Refer this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
As onActivityResult is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are always finishing your activity through:

```
setResult(someIntent, yourRequestCode);
finish();
```

If you are doing so, try to override the `onBackPressed` method and replace its default implementation with the above code.